# Continuous gesture recognizion with DTW

Tags: android, accelerometer, gesture-recognition

I try to use Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) to detect gestures performed with a smartphone by using the accelerometer sensor. I already implemented a simple DTW-algorithm.

So basicly I am comparing arrays of accelerometer-data (x,y,z) with DTW. The one array contains my predefiend gesture, the other should contain the measured values. My problem is, that the accelerometer-sensor measures continously new values and I don't know when to start the comparison with my predefined value-sequence.

I would need to know when the gesture starts and when it ends, but this might be different with different gestures. In my case all supported gestures start and end at the same point, but as far as I know I can't calculate the traveled distance from acceleration reliably.

So to sum things up: How would you determine the right time to compare my arrays using DTW?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be either you should command the user to perform the gesture at acertain pt of time and start the comparison. Or should give user the rights in form of a button to say the system to start tracing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Sadly this is not an option, because
1. it would be easier to let the user directly choose the action via tap, if he needs to press a button anyway
2. the phone-screen isn't visible for the user, because he will have it in his pockets during gesture detection

Comment: This project's documentation could help you: https://github.com/talcs/simpledtw

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, you compare your predefined gesture to **EVERY**
subsequence.
You can do this in much faster than real time (see [a]).

You need to z-normalize EVERY subsequence, and z-normalize your predefined gesture.

So, by analogy, if you stream was.....

```
NOW IS THE WINTER OF OUR DISCONTENT, MADE GLORIOUS SUMMER..
```

And your predefined word was `made`, you can compare with every marked word beginning (denoted by white space)

```
DTW(MADE,NOW)
DTW(MADE,IS)
DTW(MADE,THE)
DTW(MADE,WINTER)
```

etc

In your case, you don’t have makers, you have this...

```
NOWISTHEWINTEROFOURDISCONTENTMADEGLORIOUSSUMMER..
```

So you just test every offset

```
DTW(MADE,NOWI)
DTW(MADE, OWIS)
DTW(MADE, WIST)
DTW(MADE, ISTH)
::
DTW(MADE, TMAD)
DTW(MADE, MADE)   // Success!
```

eamonn

[a] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_qLzMMuVQg

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the comprehensible example. Do I understand right, that this will only work when the pattern in my (infinite) sequence has the same amount of samples as the predefined gesture sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You want to apply DTW not only to a time-series, but to a **continously evolving stream**. Therefore you will have to use a sliding window of n recent data points. 
This is exactly, what eamonn described in his second example. His target pattern consists of 4 events (M,A,D,E) and therefore he uses a sliding window with length of 4.

Yet in this case, he makes the assumption, that the data stream contains no distortions, such as (M,A,A,D,E). The advantage of DTW is that it allows these kind of distortions and yet recognizes the distorted target pattern as a match. In your case, distortions in time  are likely to happen. I assume that you want equal gestures performed either slow or fast as the same gesture.

Thus, the length of the sliding window must be higher than the length of the target pattern (to be able to detect a slow target gesture). This is computationally expensive.

Finally, my point is: I want to recommed you this paper
[Spring algorithm](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~christos/PUBLICATIONS/ICDE07-spring.pdf) by Sakurai, Faloutsos and Yamamuro.

They optimized the DTW algorithm for datastreams. You will no longer need more than n*n computations per incoming event but only n. It basically is DTW but cutting down all unneccesary computations and only taking the best possible alignment of the template onto the stream into account.

p.s. most of what I know about time-series and pattern matching, I learned by reading what Eamonn Keogh provided. Thanks a lot, Mr. Keogh.